# dplyr::select - Including All Other Columns at End of New Data Frame (or Beginning or Middle)

Tags: r, dplyr

When interacting with data I find the dplyr library's select() function a great way to organize my data frame columns.

One great use, if I happen to be working with a df that has many columns, I often find myself putting two variables next to each other for easy comparison. When doing this, I then need to attached all other columns either before or after.  I found the `matches(".")` function a super convenient way to do this.

For example:

```
library(nycflights13)
library(dplyr)

# just have the five columns:
select(flights, carrier, tailnum, year, month, day) 

# new order for all column:
select(flights, carrier, tailnum, year, month, day, matches(".")) 
# matches(".")  attached all other columns to end of new data frame
```

**The Question**
- I am curious if there is a better way to do this? Better in the sense of being more flexible.

For example of one issue: Is there some way to include "all other" columns at the beginning or middle of new data.frame?  (Note that `select(flights, matches("."), year, month, day, )` doesn't produce desired result, since `matches(".")` attached all columns and `year, month, day` are ignored because they are repeats of existing columns names.)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

#### Update: using dplyr::relocate()

Selected columns **at the beginning**:

```
flights %>%  
  relocate(carrier, tailnum, year, month, day)
```

Selected columns **at the end**:

```
flights %>%  
  relocate(carrier, tailnum, year, month, day, .after = last_col())
```

#### Old answer

>If you want to **reorder the columns**

All other columns **at the end**:

```
select(flights, carrier, tailnum, year, month, day, everything())
```

Or in two steps,  to select variables provided in a character vector, `one_of("x", "y", "z")`:

```
col <- c("carrier", "tailnum", "year", "month", "day")
select(flights, one_of(col), everything())
```

All other columns **at the beginning**:

```
select(flights, -one_of(col), one_of(col))
```

> If you want to **add all the data frame** again using `dplyr`:

All data frame at the end:

```
bind_cols(select(flights, one_of(col)), flights)
```

All data frame at the beginning:

```
bind_cols(flights, select(flights, one_of(col)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Though not a very elegant solution, it works.

```
  select(flights, carrier, tailnum, 
one_of(setdiff(colnames(flights),c("carrier","tailnum","year"))),year)
```

I used `setdiff` function to compare. since `select` do not accept string arguments, I have used `one_of` function. For list of many utility functions for select argument you can refer to this [post](http://www.r-bloggers.com/the-complete-catalog-of-argument-variations-of-select-in-dplyr/).

Answer (score 1):

in my view, set `!` for taking the complement of a set of variables.

```
 mtcars %>% select(c(vs,am), !c(vs,am))
```